# How to add box-shadow css property only to the bottom for the div element using css?

Tags: html, css

i want to add box-shadow only to the bottom of the div element using css.

below is the picture of what i am trying to do?
[image]

i want to get the line marked in red.

below is my code,

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container"> //this needs box-shadow bottom
        <span class="text">sometext</span>
        <div class="description">some big description</div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 32px;
    width: 316px;
    height: 225px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    border-radius: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    opacity: 1;
}

.container {
    height: 101px;
    width: 316px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29); //this adds boxshadow to all sides
}

.description {
     height: 42px;
     width: 289px;
     margin-top: 8px;
     color: black;
     display: flex;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 400;
     margin-bottom: 16px;
 `;
```

As you see the container class adds boxshadow to all sides. i want to add only for the bottom how can i do it? could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your `.container` CSS like this:

```
.container {
    height: 101px;
    width: 316px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: thanks. box-shadow to be applied is like so box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #00000029; as per the design.

Comment: this add a box shadow which is thick at the bottom.

Comment: You can make it less thicker by playing around with the pixels. Remember that the order is `top / right / bottom / left` You can also change the color. rgba means red/green/blue/alpha. There you need to add the value of your hexadecimal color, and then the alpha (how much transparency you want). Transparency values go from 0 to 1.

Comment: @Paula Hi Paula, it is actually offset-x / offset-y / blur-radius / spread-radius per MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow